# Read data from XML file insert into database

Tags: xml, frameworks, entity

I've an XML file that has 100K elements in it. In C# code, using Entity Framework, have to read data from XML file and insert/Update into four tables in SQLServer database. If we use Entity Framework as ORM, thinking of calling SaveChanges after each record from XML is inserted/updated in entities in for each loop and call Save Changes outside of for loop. Does this takes long time to do execute database insert/update statements?

If we use stored procedure, how to do this task efficiently so performance is good and won't take much time (more than 30 mins) to process 100k rows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly you should do them in batches. Have you profiled how long it takes?

Comment: I've not started working on code, trying to see different options available.

Comment: Well, go ahead and try it a couple different ways and see how it goes. Maybe try batches of different sizes and see how it goes. I don't think that doing one at a time is a good idea, and I'm positive trying to do 100K at once would be bad. But there's no way we can guess whether it will take 30 minutes or more. Just try it and see.